# Why is there no Project Item when Deploying VSIX?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx, dsl-tools

We have a VS2010 Beta 2 DSL Project , We can build, deploy and test on our Development machines and all is well i.e When we go to 'Add New Item' we can select our DSL

When it comes to giving the VSIX to someone else to try the ONLY way that they can see the associated Project Item is if they build the DSL Project on their machine, they do not need to F5, it is just a simple Build Solution and then voila they can see it.

Is this a bug or user error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to update your bits to the RC version, which are now shipping in the [VS Visualization & Modeling SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=cd443b01-d657-4f8b-b5b8-29f1e3e2c424&displaylang=en) at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=cd443b01-d657-4f8b-b5b8-29f1e3e2c424&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a known bug

I have found a workaround by adding some guids

{82b43b9b-a64c-4715-b499-d71e9ca2bd60};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}

into the csproj and manually editing the vsixmanifest to add

ItemTemplates

I created a folder called ItemTemplates and then added the generated project item Zip into the folder , I then set the Zip as Content and changed the IncludeInVSIX property to 'True'

Not pretty but it works